# Node.js auth: Using passport with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I saw this very nice article from Scotch.io:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-linking-all-accounts-together

It is from January 2014, so it's getting a bit old :) but Chris shows us how we might check the value of req.user inside the `passport.authenticate('linkedin')` callback, like so:

```
 passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
        consumerKey: linkedinConfig.clientId,
        consumerSecret: linkedinConfig.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: serverBaseUrl + '/auth/linkedin/callback'
    },
    function (req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {

        if (req.user) {
            var user = req.user;
            user.linkedin.id = profile.id;
            user.linkedin.token = token;

            user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    done(err);
                }
                else {
                    done(null, user);
                }
            });

        }
        else{
            User.findOne({'linkedin.id': profile.id}, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    done(err);
                }
                else if (user) {
                    done(null, user);
                }
                else {
                    done(null, null);
                }
            });
        }

    }
));
```

my question is - how did Chris get the req value passed to this callback?

in other words the callback signature is supposed to be this:

```
 function (token, tokenSecret, profile, done)
```

not this

```
 function (req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done)
```

...now passport appears to be standard Express middleware, with the signature of

```
module.exports = function(req,res,next){};
```

but I don't see how to access the `req` variable with Passport the way Chris does. Am I missing something from his article somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at tutorial , try this :

```
 passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
    consumerKey: linkedinConfig.clientId,
    consumerSecret: linkedinConfig.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: serverBaseUrl + '/auth/linkedin/callback',
    passReqToCallback : true
}
```

LinkedIn strategy inherits from Oauth1 strategy in this [line](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth1/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L48) explains how works , this should be sufficient. hope it helps.